# How to Parse response SAML using openAM

Tags: xml-parsing, saml, saml-2.0, openam

How to parse a response SAML 2.0 using openAM.Could anybody point to any useful link or code.

Here is my Response SAML,

```
<saml2p:Response Destination="https://www.google.com/a/squaresquare.biz/acs"   
IssueInstant="2010-08-04T17:47:20.956Z"  
xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" 
InResponseTo="djfnhepndikoonjjkeomgplmkjofobhdbdieihpa" Version="2.0" 
ID="_bd24b4a3514fd93800d2a43cafc98edb">

<saml2:Issuer xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"  
Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-
format:entity">http://my.ssodemo.url.demo.google.com/idp/shibboleth</saml2:Issuer>

<ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<ds:SignedInfo>
  <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"></ds:CanonicalizationMethod>
  <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"></ds:SignatureMethod>
  <ds:Reference URI="#_bd24b4a3514fd93800d2a43cafc98edb">
    <ds:Transforms>
      <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"></ds:Transform>
      <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
        <ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="dssaml2saml2p"></ec:InclusiveNamespaces>
      </ds:Transform>
    </ds:Transforms>
    <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"></ds:DigestMethod>
    <ds:DigestValue>m/lUCS3nvfGuSJFKAtIz+ZrfxTU=</ds:DigestValue>
  </ds:Reference>
</ds:SignedInfo>
<ds:SignatureValue>PLdYgU9u5KirVrMHNSwYvk6fQ401dMbpuiDXpapKf0eOKC6pN3g7tnTEzvfOaXhkDNXVmGN+lXQ6iUDppWpdO2MbvPVZabOBPU1aAO+CWI53ciC0rYsxpFzQLLMC/7x9Wk7VFFmYEecxAJV+lTWvp8ZKXvwqZbhiTO/23EC0xconGhnwSvKjJWQuLnMMaFWSjDFYyzgsp34cR7aX/eqhhJyA/rr2uFdmgEdagAl+/17ppgHgthgK+PJtX16AALtsoXonv6uybRCX/YiDRvM1VsdwusVq5tXh9V+bTMZcgi/3Eh+Em/OZp0En8pqOngvL19U4LfqG0yJZjoDGkpHuhA==</ds:SignatureValue>
<ds:KeyInfo>
  <ds:X509Data>
<ds:X509Certificate>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...etc.etc</ds:X509Certificate>
  </ds:X509Data>
</ds:KeyInfo>
</ds:Signature>
<saml2p:Status>
<saml2p:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success"> 
</saml2p:StatusCode>
</saml2p:Status>
<saml2:Assertion xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" Version="2.0"  
IssueInstant="2010-08-04T17:47:20.956Z" ID="_73fe28bcbb68e93df954d8e2f25097b1">
<saml2:Issuer Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid- 
format:entity">http://my.ssodemo.url.demo.google.com/idp/shibboleth</saml2:Issuer>
<saml2:Subject>
<saml2:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-
format:unspecified">my_username</saml2:NameID>
  <saml2:SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer">
    <saml2:SubjectConfirmationData NotOnOrAfter="2010-08-04T17:52:20.956Z" InResponseTo="djfnhepndikoonjjkeomgplmkjofobhdbdieihpa" Recipient="https://www.google.com/a/squaresquare.biz/acs" Address="172.24.6.38"></saml2:SubjectConfirmationData>
  </saml2:SubjectConfirmation>
</saml2:Subject>
<saml2:Conditions NotOnOrAfter="2010-08-04T17:52:20.956Z" NotBefore="2010-08-04T17:47:20.956Z">
  <saml2:AudienceRestriction>
    <saml2:Audience>google.com</saml2:Audience>
  </saml2:AudienceRestriction>
</saml2:Conditions>
<saml2:AuthnStatement
SessionIndex="f306dd2bff4e9b3ba9218bd70fbaa87404d38a4c79547ac1edc9436a9f222213" 
AuthnInstant="2010-08-04T17:47:20.953Z">
  <saml2:SubjectLocality Address="172.24.6.38"></saml2:SubjectLocality>
  <saml2:AuthnContext>
 <saml2:AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport</saml2:AuthnContextClassRef>
</saml2:AuthnContext>
</saml2:AuthnStatement>
</saml2:Assertion>
</saml2p:Response>
```

Here i want to extract the signatureValue and certificate.and how should i verify the signature and certificate after extracting.

Comment: What do you mean by parse? you want to read the raw XML and get objects?

Comment: @Stefan yes i want to parse the SAML and extract the objects,like the certificate.

Comment: Ok, so you dont want to just use OpenAM for SSO? you want to manally parse SAML

Comment: @Stefan  i have updated the question with Response SAML i recieve from Idp.Could you please help on how to extract and verify the signature and certificate.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, you dont want to use OpenAM for this. For this I suggest using the OpenSAML library which is build for more manual low-level processing of SAML messages. More information about OpenSAML https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/OpenSAML/Home
I also have a blog where I have written a few guides and tips https://blog.samlsecurity.com/categories/opensaml/

Comment: Thanks,i have used openAM for extracting the objects and able to get certain tags,
Response resp=ProtocolFactory.getInstance().createResponse("saml Response");
System.out.println("the issuer is"+resp.getIssuer().getValue());
but i am unable to get signature and certificate.and how to verify using OpenAM.does openAM provide any API for this.